# How run Select Query with LIKE on thousands of rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Newbie here. Been searching for hours now but I can seem to find the correct answer or properly phrase my search.

I have thousands of rows (orderids) that I want to put on an IN function, I have to run a LIKE at the same time on these values since the columns contains json and there's no dedicated table that only has the order_id value. I am running the query in BigQuery.

Sample Input:

ORD12345
ORD54376

Table I'm trying to Query: transactions_table

[image]

Query:

```
SELECT order_id, transaction_uuid,client_name 
FROM transactions_table 
WHERE  JSON_VALUE(transactions_table,'$.ordernum') LIKE IN ('%ORD12345%','%ORD54376%')
```

Just doesn't work especially if I have thousands of rows.

Also, how do I add the order id that I am querying so that it appears under an order_id column in the query result?

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: please add more information to your question. your code and efforts for a better results from the community.

Answer (score 1):

**Option one**

```
WITH transf as (Select order_id, transaction_uuid,client_name , JSON_VALUE(transactions_table,'$.ordernum') as o_num from transactions_table)
Select * from transf where o_num like '%ORD12345%' or o_num like '%ORD54376%'
```

**Option two**

```
split o_num by "-" as separator , create table of orders like (select 'ORD12345' as num 
Union 
Select 'ORD54376' aa num) and inner join it with transf.o_num
```

Comment: Thanks I modified option 1 to extract the exact orderid  and then just did IN on the order numbers.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `OR`:

```
WHERE JSON_VALUE(transactions_table, '$.ordernum') LIKE IN '%ORD12345%' OR
      JSON_VALUE(transactions_table, '$.ordernum') LIKE '%ORD54376%'
```

An alternative method uses regular expressions:

```
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(JSON_VALUE(transactions_table, '$.ordernum'), 'ORD12345|ORD54376')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#comparison_operators), the **LIKE** operator works as described:

> Checks if the STRING in the first operand X matches a pattern
>   specified by the second operand Y. Expressions can contain these
>   characters:
>
> A percent sign "%" matches any number of characters or
>   bytes.
>
> An underscore "_" matches a single character or byte.
>
> You can escape "\", "_", or "%" using two backslashes. For example, "\%". If
>   you are using raw strings, only a single backslash is required. For
>   example, r"\%".

Thus , the syntax would be like the following:

```
SELECT
  order_id,
  transaction_uuid,
  client_name
FROM
  transactions_table
WHERE
  JSON_VALUE(transactions_table,
    '$.ordernum') LIKE '%ORD12345%'
  OR JSON_VALUE(transactions_table,
    '$.ordernum') LIKE '%ORD54376%
```

Notice that we specify two conditions connected with the [OR](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#logical_operators) logical operator.

As a bonus information, when querying large datasets it is a good pratice to select only the columns you desire in your out output ( either in a Temp Table or final view) instead of using *, because BigQuery is columnar, one of the reasons it is faster.

As an alternative for using **LIKE**, you can use [REGEXP_CONTAINS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_contains), according to the documentation:

> Returns TRUE if value is a partial match for the regular expression, regex.

Using the following syntax:

```
REGEXP_CONTAINS(value, regex)
```

However, it will also work if instead of a regex expression you use a *STRING* between single/double quotes. In addition, you can use the pipe operator (|) to allow the searched components to be logically ordered, when you have more than expression to search, as follows:

```
where regexp_contains(email,"gary|test")
```

I hope if helps.